# Errorr while trying to run aws iam list-users Command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Getting the following error while trying to access aws iam list-users

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListUsers operation: User: arn:aws:iam::138437462432:user/user_name is not authorized to perform: iam:ListUsers on resource: arn:aws:iam::138437462432:user/

Answer (score 1):

For the respective user. Administrator Access is missing . Once I attached that access it works fine

[image]